# How secure is TFS Online?

Tags: security, team-foundation-server

A colleague just asked me how secure is [TFS Online](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/)?

His question is deeper than the [MSDN security documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252512%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

What he really wants to know is, if there was some rogue Microsoft employee, is TFS Online secure enough that the data is safe?

In other words, **is his code safe from Microsoft**?

Comment: Your data is not encrypted.  That should be enough.

Comment: tinfoil hats make it safe enough. Ramhound has a point tho.

Comment: Lol, He's already wearing the tinfoil.  So we're good.  I cant quite tell if @Ramhound is being sarcastic tho, so I miss that point.

Comment: I an not saying your information isn't protected in other ways but your information is not encrypted thus **anyone** with access could access your files.  My advice don't use it for a billion dollar software idea.

Comment: @paqogomez - actually dead serious.   Your files not being encrypted should be a serious consideration

Comment: *Of course* "an MS employee" has access to his data -- it's *their* service.  If he's that paranoid, don't use it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft recently published a [TFS Online Security Whitepaper](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/team-services-security-whitepaper) that talks about the different security controls Microsoft uses. They describe, in my opinion, reasonable protections given the state of the market today.

> [I]s his code safe from Microsoft?

The paper mentions the following controls to protect from Microsoft employees:

1. Encryption of data at rest via SQL Server TDE (Transparent Data Encryption).
2. Encryption of data in transit via HTTPS.

If employees must get access during "a live site incident or other approved maintenance activity, which is logged and monitored", access is restricted to those that need access and have passed background checks.